# How to enable/disable the anchor tag used as a button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enable and disable the anchor tag that has been used as a button. I want to perform this action using JavaScript. Basically I have some condition written and inside that condition I want to enable and disable that button (anchor tag).

This is the button on which I want to perform the action:

```
<div class="row my-2 text-right">
    <div class="col-12">
        <a href="javascript:saveQuote();" class="btn btn-primary">Save Quote</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Below is my script where I want to handle enabling and disabling of button (anchor tag):**

```
function getS2List( b2, callback ){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/url/" + b2,
        type: "GET", 
        async: false,
        success: function(response){  
            for(var i = 0; i < response.activeCustomer.length; i++) {
                if(response.activeCustomer[i] == 'Y'){
                     // disable Save Quote button (anchor tag)
                }else{
                    // enable save quote button
                }
            }
        },  
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
            alert( xhr.responseText ); 
            return {};
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Anchor tag shouldn't be used as a button

Comment: What is a "disabled anchor"? What should it look like? How should it work? If the element is acts as a button you should _use_ the `<button>` element which _can_ be easily (and recognisably) disabled.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with both @Andy but unfortunately I cannot change that.

Comment: So that leaves the question "what does a disabled anchor look like, and how does it function"? You may as well just hide/show it using a class. @rsharma

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="row my-2 text-right">
    <div class="col-12">
        <a href="javascript:saveQuote();" id="saveButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save Quote</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Three ways to disable the link/button

```
// disable Save Quote button (anchor tag)
$("#saveButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("$saveButton").attr('disabled', true);
$("#saveButton").attr('disabled', 'true');

// enable save quote button
$("#saveButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("$saveButton").attr('disabled', true);
$("#saveButton").attr('disabled', 'true');
```

> CSS to display as disable

```
#saveButton.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: _"Three ways to disable the link/button"_ - not as long as it is an actual _link_, those do not have a `disabled` attribute. You can _set_ it, sure - but that won't have any effect.